# Multipage Portfolio Page routing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a new developer and still learning. I am wanting to make a portfolio page with a few different pages for an about, contact, and individual project pages. I have attached my current sitemap which I am hoping to create. What would be the best way to create these routes for the pages?

I know some HTML, CSS, Javascript, and some React.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would make a site with a homepage, where the visitor can see what this site is about. Then a navbar (navigation bar) that sticks to the top of the page.

I've made an example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/ske8mcg9/3/
You may use and edit this if you like :)

Also some things that a good navbar **must** have:

- The navbar must have a higher `z-index` than the elements in the page, otherwise the navbar will drop down behind the elements in the page.
- The navbar must stick to the top of the page (that's not in the example, but you can do that yourself very easily)
- It's nice when you see that you're hovering over something, e.g. color change, shadow, scale, opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the links to the dropdowns! I think I have the navbar down no problem. My question is more along the lines of when something is clicked on the nav bar (for instance about), I wanted the page to display page.com/about instead of loading in another html page like page.com/about.html. Would I have to do this in something like React Router?